# While using Route the site is not loading , when i am wrapping inside BroswerRoute only its working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

***this my App.js Code , not able to find any solution .All item are imported and its working fine if its not wrapped in Route***

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom"
import Home from './Pages/Home';
import SignUpPage from './Pages/SignUpPage';


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Route >
          <Home />`enter code here`

        </Route>
        <Route path='/signup'>
          <SignUpPage />
        </Route>


      </BrowserRouter>

    </div >
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What version of `react-router-dom` is installed? You can check by running `npm list react-router-dom` in the terminal from the project's root directory.

Comment: yeah its installed . thanks for trying to help . my issue got resolved .

Answer (score 0):

You're not wrapping your routes correctly, this is how it should be with react-router-dom v6:

```
import React from "react";
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Pages/Home";
import SignUpPage from "./Pages/SignUpPage";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/signup" element={<SignUpPage />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

You wrap your routes in a `routes` component, imported from `react-router-dom`. You can Then declare your route on one line `<Route path="/insertPathHere" element={<YourComponent/>} />`